# I want if user register successfully then user will come next time the registration will not be show for that user

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Can you read my question let me know the solution on that.

I want if user register successfully then user will come next time the registration will not be show for that user.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `config/session.php` file you you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session to be allowed to remain idle before it expires.

```
[
    ...

    'lifetime' => 120, // change this to the desired number of minutes
    'expire_on_close' => false,

    ...
]
```

One more thing you can do is implement the `remember me` feature that comes out of the box with a brand new installation of laravel. more info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#remembering-users